# Template literals in javascript

Tags: javascript, templates

in javascript I can write the follow code:

```
response = {
    status: 1,
    data: {
        key : 2
    }
}
var result = `status is ${response.status}, data key is ${response.data.key}`
console.log(result);
```

the output is

```
status is 1, data key is 2
```

Is there any libs provide the way to do it in java, providing the following function?

```
String xxxFunction(Map map, String template)
```

please note the usage of `${response.data.key}`, map in map

Answer (score 23):

You can make use of `String.format`

```
String template = "status is %s, data key is %s"
String result = String.format(template, status, key);
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, you should expand your answer by providing some explaining text and documentation for further reading.

Comment: Not the same thing...

Comment: @theMayer - what do you mean ?

Comment: @MasterJoe, string.format is not the same thing - not even close to the same thing - as a template literal. In fact, it’s what you’re trying to avoid with a template literal. So the correct answer is “Java doesn’t offer this.” Game, set, and match to C#

Answer (score 3):

You can try [StrSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) from Apache common text

```
 Map valuesMap = HashMap();
 valuesMap.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
 valuesMap.put("target", "lazy dog");
 String templateString = "The ${animal} jumps over the ${target}. ${undefined.number:-1234567890}.";
 StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(valuesMap);
 String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString);
```

You can find a download link / dependency [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/)

Comment: does it allow condition based string substitution?

Comment: What's your requirement @gaurav

Comment: @Manh I want to substitute strings based on if-else conditions.e.g. https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/doc/templates.md#conditionals